# run on all object's parameters java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've an model:

`User(id, firstName, lastName);`

I get the user from `POST` request in Java Spring boot framework using `@ModelAttribute` Annotation in the prototype.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User updateUser(@ModelAttribute("User") User user) {
        //persist.save(user);
        return user;
    }
```

In the `POST` request user can send parameters with `null` value, and I want to determine who they are.

For example:

`POST` request: `http://localhost:8801/users/update?id=1&firstName=itzik`

the `@ModelAttribute` will cast the values into `User` model and give `null` values to the empty parameter that didn't sent with the user.

So the results will be:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "itzik",
    "lastName": null, 
}
```

I'm trying to determine which parameters hold value `null` to prevent them from damage my whole data record before save it.

I have searched a way to run on all object parameters and didn't found one that works,

Thanks!

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String uid;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private int permission;
    private int department;
    private boolean deleted;

    public User(String uid, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phone, int permission, int department, boolean deleted) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.permission = permission;
        this.department = department;
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `Objects.requireNonNull(...)` on all three parameters of `User` inside the constructor / `@JsonCreator`? By doing that, Spring will receive the deserialization exception and return it to your caller without you even being bothered to double check.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ can you attach an example? I don't really understand you.

Comment: Can you post the code of the class User? I will work on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found better solution that fit to my case.

I've found this method and place it on my Model class:

```
public void setObject(Object other) {
        try {
            Field[] fields = new Field[0];
            Class clazz = this.getClass();
            do {
                fields = (Field[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(fields, clazz.getDeclaredFields());
                clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();

            } while (!clazz.equals(Object.class));
            for (Field f : fields) {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                Object value = f.get(other);
                if (value != null) {
                    f.set(this, value);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And update the route:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User updateUser(@ModelAttribute("User") User user) {
        User oldUser = persist.loadObject(User.class, user.getId());
        oldUser.setObject(user);
        persist.save(oldUser);
        return oldUser;
    }
```

The function run from the lastest object state on the model that arrive from the POST request and update the fields only if is not `null`, which mean its act like `Union` logic operation.

Comment: If I may give you my advice, I don't think this is a better solution. You are doing reflection (heavy operation in terms of performance) in order to take the new user and retrieve only the non null values that were sent, joining them with the previous values. What if the user wants to change a non null value of user? Your code will forbid them to do so. Also, your object contains non final fields which is never a good practice for POJOs (it means that another thread may potentially change one value without the other thread knowing it so creating data inconsistency).

Comment: If you're happy with this solution good for you, but I can tell you it's a not a very solid code design :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Spring Framework, there is a serialization/deserialization happening "behind the scenes" which involves your POJOs.

For example, into this endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public User updateUser(@ModelAttribute("User") User user) {
    //persist.save(user);
    return user;
}
```

... the HTTP protocol will bring a Text/JSON content which represents a `User`, but will not send an instance of `User`. Same way, when your `return user;` in your method you're returing an instance of `User`, but the client is getting a serialized Json representing your user (and this is because Spring, behind the scenes, will serialize the class for you).

Spring will hence go looking for the constructor of `User` and deserialize the Json String into an `User` instance.

Hence, if your `User` constructor was containing a null check:

```
public User(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = Objects.requireNonNull(lastName, "lastName should not be null");
}
```

... then as soon as Spring was trying to initialize the `User` instance, it would receive a `NullPointerException` that will be reported directly to the caller.
Your method wouldn't even be called.

Hence, by protecting your `User` constructor with non-null checks, you guarantee that from the very first line of code inside your `updateUser` endpoint, the `User` object is correctly formed without need to do any further check

---

Complete example:

```
public class User {

    private final int id; //<- make all fields final (they can't change any longer after construction)
    private final String uid;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String email;
    private final String phone;
    private final int permission;
    private final int department;
    private final boolean deleted;

    public User(String uid, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phone, int permission, int department, boolean deleted) {
        this.uid = Objects.requireNonNull(uid); //<- wrap all sets by requireNonNull
        this.firstName = Objects.requireNonNull(firstName);
        this.lastName = Objects.requireNonNull(lastName);
        this.email = Objects.requireNonNull(email);
        this.phone = Objects.requireNonNull(phone);
        this.permission = Objects.requireNonNull(permission);
        this.department = Objects.requireNonNull(department);
        this.deleted = Objects.requireNonNull(deleted);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your Answer, I need to make constructor for each parameter in class `User`, With `Objects.requireNonNull(...)` method to each one of them.

Comment: @itzikb no, I just used one parameter because there were too many, but you should keep one single constructor taking all the parameters, and each parameter you want not to be null should be wrapped by "requireNonNull()" as I did in my one-parameter example.

Comment: @itzikb I've added the whole class revisited